# Error message: 'Please make sure that you do not have 2 templates with the same alias' umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I keep getting this error message every time i go to save on of my pages? Does anyone know why? I have looked on google, but have found no solution that is working for me....

Thanks

Comment: When posting questions like this, you need to provide more information, e.g. Umbraco version number, OS version and whether this is a local or server installation.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, this may actually be a permissions issue. Check that you have write permissions on all the relevant folders including the ones containing your templates (either `views/` or `masterpages/`). See here for [details of what should be applied](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup).